# April Tags 2 Camera Setup

Tags: camera, ros

I am working with apriltags2_ros to try to do a simple tracking but am unable to set up my webcam to work with the apriltags2_ros package. I am using this link as a reference, http://wiki.ros.org/apriltags2_ros/Tu... but when I launch the continuous_detection.launch and run rqt and image_view there is no image displayed from my webcam so how would I set it up to work with my webcam?

Comment: Are you able to see your source images in rqt_image_view ??

Comment: No, no image appears.

Comment: Your link above doesn't work.  But before you get the tracking to work, you need to be able to correctly publish the images from your Webcam and see them in rqt_image_view

Comment: Can you give some help with the steps to do that?

Comment: What ros driver are you using for your camera?

Comment: I haven't set that up. This is my first time using ros

Comment: What camera are you using?